# SVG text animate font styles

Tags: animation, svg

I want to make an animation that looks like a google search box

I have a text path where the word appears in a 'bold' font.

I would like the word to animate so that the first letter appears 'regular',  then the first and second, then the first second and third etc.

Is this possible to do with an svg animation?

```
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="30 -50 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

  <path id="path1">
    <animate attributeName="d" from="m100,50 h0" to="m100,50 h1100" dur="5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>

// this text "types"

  <text font-size="90" font-family="Montserrat" fill='black'>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1">Google is</textPath>
  </text>

// I want this text to animate the "font-style"

  <text font-size="90" font-family="Montserrat" fill='black' x="100" y="200">
    Google is gold
    <animate attributeType="CSS" ....  />
  </text>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I need to give each <tspan> an id to do this? Also would I animate this by writing font-style='regular' within the animate tag and giving each one a different begin="?s" ?

Comment: If you want them to chain, animate each on the `<animation id>`.end event of the previous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to put the letters in separate  tags within the textPath so you can target them individually with animations.

I've just done the first letter but you could extend this to all the letters if you wished.

```html
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="30 -50 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

  <path id="path1">
    <animate attributeName="d" from="m100,50 h0" to="m100,50 h1100" dur="5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>

// this text "types"

  <text font-size="90" font-family="Montserrat" fill='black'>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1">Google is</textPath>
  </text>

// I want this text to animate the "font-style"

  <text font-size="90" font-family="Montserrat" fill='black' x="100" y="200">
    <tspan>G<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="font-weight" from="700" to="100" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/></tspan>oogle is gold
    
  </text>
```

Comment: This has been very helpful. I'm stuck on chaining the animations. This is my best attempt, could you have a look? https://plnkr.co/edit/Yg3F37QtUUcdkoHlOIeN?p=info It should work like this: Top row - From 0s each letter should appear one after the other (visibility hidden to visible, then hold) and Bottom row - 0s whole word appears bold, and each letter changes (font -weight: 700 to 100 one after the other, and hold) Then I would like the entire sequence to start again.

Comment: Can you ask another question and put your code in that?

Comment: Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933509/svg-animating-visibility-and-chaining